# Button seems to be permanently pressed when closing my laptop on ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, laptop

I am using a razer blade stealth 13 from 2016 running ubuntu 22.04.1. Sometimes when I close my laptop and open it back up it seems as if a button on my keyboard were permanently pressed. This causes the password field to fill in uncontrollably. The only way to fix it is by shutting the laptop down by holding the power button and starting it up again.
Is there a way to fix this issue?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: if this is an unfortunate interaction between a physical problem (key touches the screen) + state lost during resume, you could probably try and press again the offending key(s) to "resynchronize" its (their) state: better than a reboot. Anyway identifying if that's the case might help find a solution (xdotool...)

Comment: Working with a remote access from a 2nd system would be handy too.